# In c#, how to protect the about us form from tampering?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have built a c# image processing application that needs to be given to someone with the source code. I have an about us page which mentions that the software is built by me, im afraid that the other person might remove my credentials from that page and use his own. I cant spend on expensive tools for this.

Is there any way I can bind the about us form with the main application in someway that makes it impossible to alter or remove? The software should not work without that form.

Comment: short answer: no. long answer: noooo. nothing you can do in code. _especially_ when someone else has - and therefore can change - the code. you can only add a clause to your license and hope people adhere to it.

Comment: As already noted, there's no technical solution to this, but you can take legal precautions to it: Add a clear license document and let the other party sign a corresponding contract. It's best to contact a lawyer on this.

Comment: Well, the technical solution is to turn it into a web app so you keep control of it ..